# Mime type is different than extension

Tags: file-upload, mime-types, file-extension

I upload an image and check for it's mime type and extension. For some reason they don't match. I have mime type image/png and extension gives jpg.

How is that possible and how can I fix this? This has obviously something to do with the image but how can this be fixed?

Comment: Well, probably it is a png compressed file. Just because you put a `.jpg` behind its name does not change its content, nor its mime type. Judging a files mime type by the "name extension" is a thing from the 80th, things have advanced since. At least on most systems. There is indeed, as always, one exception left that _partly_ still relies on those name extensions, whyever.

Comment: I agree on you that it has something to do with the image and I agree with you that this check is very old. For now we have managed to fix this with another image but that does not change the code as that still remains the same. Anyway thanks!